# Why does my ASP.Net custom control render two id attributes on my first child control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm writing a small ASP.Net custom control inheriting from CompositeControl.  The control is just a panel containing two subpanels with a label in each subpanel.  When rendered, I am seeing in the HTML source that the first child control of my custom control gets two id attributes - the first being the id of the custom control itself and the second being the ID property I assign to the first child control.  Why is this happening?

Code:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MessageBox runat=server></{0}:MessageBox>")]
public class MessageBox : CompositeControl {

    private Panel _MessageHeaderContainer = null;
    private Label _MessageHeaderLabel = null;
    private Panel _MessageDetailsContainer = null;
    private Label _MessageDetailsLabel = null;

    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey {
        get {
            return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {

        // Message header area.
        _MessageHeaderContainer = new Panel();
        _MessageHeaderContainer.ID = "HeaderContainer";
        _MessageHeaderContainer.CssClass = "__MessageBox_Container";
        this.Controls.Add(_MessageHeaderContainer);

        // Message header text.
        _MessageHeaderLabel = new Label();
        _MessageHeaderLabel.ID = "HeaderLabel";
        _MessageHeaderLabel.Text = "[ Header ]";
        _MessageHeaderContainer.Controls.Add(_MessageHeaderLabel);

        // Message details area.
        _MessageDetailsContainer = new Panel();
        _MessageDetailsContainer.ID = "DetailsContainer";
        this.Controls.Add(_MessageDetailsContainer);

        // Message details text.
        _MessageDetailsLabel = new Label();
        _MessageDetailsLabel.ID = "DetailsLabel";
        _MessageDetailsLabel.Text = "[ Details ]";
        _MessageDetailsContainer.Controls.Add(_MessageDetailsLabel);

    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
        AddAttributesToRender(output);

        // Render the box.
        _MessageHeaderContainer.RenderControl(output);
        _MessageDetailsContainer.RenderControl(output);
    }
}
```

Usage in ASPX page:

```
<cc:MessageBox ID="ctlMessageBox" runat="server" />
```

HTML output:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox">
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox_HeaderContainer" class="__MessageBox_Container">
        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox_HeaderLabel">[ Header ]</span>
    </div><div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox_DetailsContainer">
        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox_DetailsLabel">[ Details ]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It also seems like any property I assign to the control itself (i.e., this.CssClass = "xxxx") gets assigned to control's outermost, auto-generated div tag as well as the first child control's rendered div tag.

Comment: Removing the AddAttributesToRender(output) line from the Render function stops adding all of the attributes of the root tag to the first child. I'm not sure what the point of the AddAttributesToRender function is... can anyone enlighten me as to why I would call this function?

Comment: You would call it if you wanted more control over how your Custom Control Renders.

It adds the attributes that should be assigned to the custom control (style, etc., from the ASPX markup and other sources) to next tag that is rendered.  You do not need it because you are letting ASP.NET take care of rendering.  If you override the Render method (like my example), you would need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by removing the `RenderContents` method entirely - don't replace it with anything. By default, composite controls render all their child controls. If you do this, your control produces clean markup:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test_HeaderContainer" class="__MessageBox_Container">
     <span id="test_HeaderLabel">[ Header ]</span>
    </div>
    <div id="test_DetailsContainer">
     <span id="test_DetailsLabel">[ Details ]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you've noted, the `AddAttributesToRender` method is the culprit - it's a convenience method renders all the top-level control's attributes (whether the current context is the top-level control or not). The only reason you would call this is if you were taking full control of the rendering process yourself and wanted to render all the attributes for the top-level control in a single statement.

Answer (score -1):

This is the ID ASP.NET assigns the Custom Control as a whole.  If you wrap your Custom Control in a Div or Span (within the Custom Control code itself, not in the markup) the ID will be assigned to that instead of your first inner "control".

Something like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  AddAttributesToRender(writer);

  //must render tag or first inner control will get two IDs
  writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);

  //render child controls here...

  writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

Comment: I did this by adding output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div) as the first line under the comment "Render the box" (and I added the appropriate output.RenderEndTag() after rendering the child controls.  Now the HTML output includes an enclosing div tag with a duplicate id as the custom control's own "root" div tag.  Basically I have <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox"><div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctlMessageBox">< child control stuff /></div></div>.  I still have duplicate control id's in the rendered output - not good.

Comment: Try overriding "Render", and not "RenderContents"  Also, try removing the HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey.